# How to detect const modifier in LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I realized that Constant in LLVM is not the same as variable with c/c++'s const modifier.

Is there any way for me to differentiate C/C++ variables with const modifier in LLVM from those that do not have it? (all variables including globals)

Answer (score 1):

LLVM IR isn't intended to represent the source type system, it's an intermediate representation and contains the type information that's useful for compiling, which will resemble the source types but need not capture all aspects. If you want the *source* type system, you have to look at the debug information, which need not be present, but if it is present it is at least intended to contain the data you want.

You can start looking at [DIType](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DIType.html). Be warned that this code isn't awfully well documented.

Global variables have a convenient method, though, [isConstant()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html#aa859e108741fa64681b63f0c0c672512).

Comment: Thank for DIType suggestion. Unfortunately, I didn't see any useful functions inside. Also, as for isConstant(), it only detects for LLVM type Constant, which globalVariables are derived from. Thus, all global variables return true for isConstant() regardless of if they have const modifier or not

Comment: IsConstant returns an argument to the constructor IIRC, and DIType and the other DI* are indeed not simple or well documented.